# Can Mac KeyNote presentations exported for Windows be shown in good quality and be edited?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, iwork-keynote

A friend asked me this:

> ...I stopped using **KeyNote** for one simple reason –
>   contrary to the Mac marketing blurb,
>   the final
>   presentations do  NOT work fine on
>   **Windows PCs** – they look **distorted** and
>   have formatting quirks which **cannot be
>   corrected** because the
>   Windows/Powerpoint  file it has
>   supposedly been saved as is in fact a
>   non-editable file,  kind of like a
>   **pdf**.

**Is there a way to create Mac KeyNote presentation files so they look nice on Windows and can be edited?**

Answer (score 0):

It can be exported to the Powerpoint format (.ppt, not pptx). And so is editable by Microsoft PowerPoint.

```
File > Export
```

The "look" depends on the complexity of the presentation.

But the distorted look when exported in PDF is odd. Since when I used it, it looked exactly like the Keynote version.

Answer (score 0):

Exported Keynote to PowerPoint presentations:

1. Yes, can be edited.
2. Can look just as good as native PowerPoint. I use Keynote almost exclusively and have not noticed any deal breaking negatives when exporting to PowerPoint. However, you must open the exported Powerpoint version and go through the whole deck to make sure that everything did port correctly. Pay close attention to animations.